# Insert data to clickhouse using a CSV file adding '&' to first record with CURL | Bash

Tags: bash, csv, curl, clickhouse

I'm having issues while trying to insert data using a csv file to clickhouse using CURL, the very first value is adding some characters and looks like follow:

```
┌─name─ ┬─lastname─┐
│&'Mark'│ Olson    │
│ Joe   │ Robins   │
└────── ┴──────────┘
```

my CSV file is ok, it is like this:

```
'Mark','Olson'
'Joe','Robins'
```

as you can see the table is adding the first value in first record as `&'Mark'`

This is my code in bash

```
query="INSERT INTO Myschema.persons FORMAT CSV"
cat ${csv} | curl -X POST -d "$query" $user:$password@localhost:8123 --data-binary @-
```

Do you know what's the problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I think you should use following format where query is part of url

```
cat *.csv |curl http://localhost:8123/?query=INSERT%20INTO%20Myschema.persons%20FORMAT%20CSV' --data-binary @-
```

I am not sure why your curl is not working but my best guess is that Clickhouse has parsing rules which are not able to consume your specified format, `${query}` and `${csv}` both being parameters to POST are getting appended by '&' in final http url, while parsing Clickhouse is unable to consider this case.

Quotes from clickhouse documentation -

> You can send the query itself either in the POST body, or in the URL
>   parameter.

and

> The POST method of transmitting data is necessary for INSERT queries.
>   In this case, you can write the beginning of the query in the URL
>   parameter, and use POST to pass the data to insert. The data to insert
>   could be, for example, a tab-separated dump from MySQL. In this way,
>   the INSERT query replaces LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE from MySQL.

Check here for more details and examples - https://clickhouse.yandex/docs/en/interfaces/http_interface/

Comment: You're right, this get fixed, but I'll edit your answer, the http part should be double quoted.